# Can't install json-server

Tags: npm, json-server

I am trying to install JSON-Server, but it's not working!

I have used the following command: `npm install -g json-server`

Here is the error message:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: Do you see "permission denied" in the error? And did you read the last 3 lines of the error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use  **sudo** before command :

`sudo npm install -g json-server`